# Can I restructure contracts?

Tags: madden-16

In previous Madden games I've played, restructuring the contracts of current players was a huge part of managing your cap space.

In Madden 16, I don't see any way to do this.

**Can I renegotiate a player's current contract? How?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now played more than 30 years of franchise in this version of Madden.

You cannot re-negotiate contracts.

This has resulted in me negotiating much shorter contracts in general. Later in a player's career their salary often times balloons to a huge level. In situations where I would have re-negotiated in the past, I now often release the player and then immediately re-sign them from free agency for a much lower contract. This is only worth it when the savings are greater than the resulting cap penalty.